# Recyclerview not scrolling with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in BottomsheetDialogFrament

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using below layout for bottomsheet layout.
And the RecyclerView with same layout is working for other lists.
But only with StaggeredGridLayoutManager, list is not scrolling at all.
Please note I have searched and tried other solutions available at Stackoverflow with no success.
Kindly check below layout and let me know how I can resolve this issue.

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner">
    <View
            android:id="@+id/headerview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_header_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_header_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@drawable/navigationview_header_viwe"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            style="@style/Avenir_Heavy"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerview"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textColor="@color/list_footer_text_color"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_20dp"/>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/footerview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_header_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_header_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@drawable/navigationview_header_viwe"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_tv"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_20dp"/>

    <com.jamhub.barbeque.util.helpers.DynamicFilterButtonFlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/filterButtonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/flowLayoutMarginTop"
            android:layout_below="@+id/footerview"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/footerview"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_tv"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/Avenir_Light"
            android:text="@string/bottomsheet_footer"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/list_footer_text_color"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you able to see content of recyclerview ? coz your nestedscrollview height is 0

Comment: Yes, I can see the contents but only issue is list is not scrolling